# Reverse / Delete SPCascadedropdowns filter effect

Tags: spcascadedropdowns

This may sound like a silly question. I'm sorry if it truly is.

So, I have a field `Product Number` that is filtered via `SPCascadedropdowns`. I would like to make this filtering conditional. Based on the value selected in a second field called `Order type` I would like to trigger this filter - or reverse the effect.

`Order type` can take two different values, "New Order" and "Follow-up Order". In case of a new order I want the `Product Number` field to display all possible product numbers. In case of a follow-up order I want the product numbers displayed to be restricted to product number which have previously been ordered by the specific customer (Value of `Customer Name` field).

Applying the SPCascadedropdowns filter is straight forward.

**My question is: Once I have already applied the filter, how can I actually reverse that effect? How can I delete the applied filter?**

Here is my current code:

```
    // Function that will filter Product Numbers based on selected Customer Name
    // Filtering will be conditional, depending whether this is a new order or a
    // follow up order. If this is a new order then no filtering should apply
    var ordertypeField = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('Order_x0020_type');
    var FilterProductNumber = function() { 
        var ordertype = ordertypeField.GetValue(); 
        if (ordertype == 'Follow-up Order') {
            myJQ().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
                relationshipList: "Orders",
                relationshipListParentColumn: "Customer_x0020_Name",
                relationshipListChildColumn: "Product_x0020_Number",
                parentColumn: "Customer Name",
                childColumn: "Product Number",
                debug: true
            });
        } else {
            // We need to add a filter that will return all product numbers into the field
            // lift the filter settings
            
            // ?????????

        }
    };
    // Execute Filtering initially with first load of site
    FilterProductNumber();
    //Execute filtering in case that anything changes in my form
    $(this).change(function () {alert ("trigger filtering"); FilterProductNumber();});
```

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're asking. What would trigger the removal of the filter? Are you wanting to reset the dropdowns based on whether they select "Follow-up Order" or "New Order"???

Comment: Yes, exactly. In case the user selects "Follow-up" order I would like to trigger the filter. In case that the user selects "New Order" I would like to reset the filter.

So: 
#1 Follow-up Order -> filtered Product Number list
#2 New Order -> full Product Number list
If the user changes his mind and selects New Order instead of Follow-up Order #2 must hold true (-> reset).